# Can not setup Mysql

Tags: installation, mysql

I was trying to setup mysql with this command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now i am getting this error

```
    start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

please help me to install mysql

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the lines before `start: Job failed to start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the Software Center, mysql-server is an empty package and depends on the latest version, which is determined by the MySQL maintainer. So you can try to install the latest version of mysql-server manually via

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

or try to use the Ubuntu Software Center. In case of doubt do an apt-get update and upgrade, just to be sure.

If this all doesn't work and if you don't find any solution, you could give [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-linux.html) a try, which is a package that includes Apache, PHP and MySQL. Then you can start the MySQL server with a small, nice Python Interface by just clicking on "Start".

Hope this helps